# "Non-refundable move in/move out fee" Interpretation

Tags: conjunctions, slash

In the sentence:

> There is a $500.00 non-refundable move in/move out fee and $500.00
> deposit for moves and deliveries that will be returned if no damage to
> common areas has been reported.

Does the phrase "There is a $500.00 non-refundable move in/move out fee" imply a singular fee, which covers the cost for moving in and moving out? Or does it imply that the $500.00 fee could be either a move in or a move out fee.

Is this just ambiguously written such that it could be correctly interpreted either way?

*Edit: I'm not interested in how this will be interpreted by a lawyer, but instead a linguist.*

Comment: It implies that moving **in** or **out** will cost you a $500 non-refundable fee. This ikind of fee is typical in condo situations.

Comment: @Lambie I think their question is whether they'll be charged $500 when they first move in, and another $500 when they later move out. Or just one charge that covers both.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, and I have answered that,  haven't I? No, it is not one charge. It is at the time of moving in and at the time of moving out. Gees.

Comment: Ask the people who want the money, not random people on the internet.

Comment: @Lambie If that's really what they mean, I think they would say "$500 move-in fee, $500 move-out fee, and $500 deposit". Their use of singular "is" suggests a single fee.

Comment: @devloco You'll know the context and therefore the answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer turns on legal matters and standard practice, not the exact text as presented. If the answer matters, ***ask the people who wrote it.***

Comment: (Obviously, *in practice,* even if the letting agency would *like* to charge tenants $500 to move in and ***another $500*** to move out, they won't always get the second payment. People who've moved somewhere else might not be easily traced by debt collectors - and in the UK at least, they might feasibly win a court case on the grounds that they'd been bullied into signing an unfair contract, so professional bailiffs might not fancy the job anyway.)

Comment: This was orinally asked by someone on SE Law, but I can't find the question. It's a legal matter, not English.

Comment: Thank you all for the interesting input. I don't agree with closing a question because it's about language that could be found in a legal document (just like all language I'll point out). I was genuinely curious about the standard and agreed-upon usage of the forward slash in a sentence like this, if there was one at all; you can rest assured I will not be taking these enlightened arguments (or any others) into a courthouse. As for the *English* matter of whether this sentence has an unambiguous meaning, I think requiring context or further clarification from the writer answers that.

Comment: The answer, "yes, the sentence is ambiguous," isn't in the question. I'm asking if there is a well defined meaning for the forward slash that would make this sentence unambiguous. However, something that is definitely frowned upon here at ELU SE is answering questions in the comments section.

Comment: Since you didn't know whether it meant one or the other, it's ambiguous to *you*. The comments indicate that it's ambiguous to others, too. There might be a customary interpretation within the legal profession, but that's best discovered by asking lawyers, not people familiar with English usage in general.

Comment: If there was a definitive way, according to the English lang., to interpret the slash in this sentence, then even if I didn't know whether it meant one or the other, it would not be an ambiguous sentence. If I didn't know and so I considered it "ambiguous to me" that would just mean that I did not know how to interpret it according to this definitively correct way. The question of what is this correct way, or if there even was a correct way is what I came here to find out. The question of how it can be interpreted in different contexts (e.g. legal contexts) is not what I came here to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed an ambiguity here. The use of the slash, and the awkward name that is given to the fee, contribute to the confusion caused by the ambiguity, but the core of the ambiguity is independent of that; it is a matter of how the sentence fits the context in which it appears.

To see this, consider a different example. Suppose you have a membership in a fitness club, that, for an annual fee, allows you to use its swimming pool, gymnasium, etc., as much as you want. The standard annual fee, however, does not include using the sauna. So somewhere in the paperwork about your membership, you find this sentence:

> There is a £___ fee for using the sauna.

Here the name of the fee is unproblematic, and there are no slashes. Nevertheless, one may reasonably wonder whether the fee is one flat fee for using the sauna throughout the period of the membership, or it is the fee that will be charged for each instance of using the sauna. (The amount of the fee may enable one to make a reasonable guess as to which interpretation is likely to have been intended, but that would still be a guess.)

In the OP's example there is a fee that is charged for moving, which includes both moving in and moving out. Like in the sauna example, that, however, does not tell us whether the specified amount of the fee that covers all the moves that the document is about, or that amount is charged separately for each instance of moving.

Considering the matter in the most general terms, saying that there is a fee (charge, price, etc.) of such-and-such amount for something is incomplete, unless it is also specified, or understood, how much of that something the amount is for: is the fee charged per year, per hour, per kilogram, per person . . . . Of course, in the real-life use of such expressions, the context will usually narrow down the range of the possibilities, and may sometimes narrow it down to a single one, thus rendering the expression practically unambiguous.

For example, if one saw the sign specifying the fee for sauna use posted at the entrance to the sauna, it would probably be obvious that the fee is charged for each instance of using it. In my example, however, the sentence appears in the context of the paperwork about annual membership, and that makes the alternative interpretation possible, that it is a fee for unlimited use throughout the year.

The OP did not tell us exactly what the document in which the sentence appears is, but it seems to be about some long-term arrangements. Because the document as a whole is about the long term-arrangements, the sentence may be reasonably interpreted as specifying one fee that covers all instances of moving-in-or-moving-out that occur in the relevant period. It can, however, also be interpreted as specifying a fee that will be charged for each instance of moving-in-or-moving-out.